# import backup of old table to new table with more columns

Tags: mysql

I have a backup.sql which contain 1 table with about 4000+ records and the respective table has 192 columns.

I need to import it to the new table having 402 columns. I would like to keep the new columns value to null or 0 as default. I tried importing with phpmyadmin and it fails.

Comment: What fails?  What error messages do you see?

Comment: I added one INSERT row from old table 

`INSERT INTO accounts VALUES ('2', '0', .......);` 
and it shows this error  `#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`